# .desktop file will not open in Google Chrome when launched from SpaceFm

Tags: unity, firefox, google-chrome, .desktop

While using Google Chrome I often drag website links from the address bar into a folder on the desktop for later reference. This creates a `.desktop` file that is essentially a link to a webpage.

These desktop files can be opened easily from Nautilus & PCmanFM by simply by double-clicking to open them, however, when I open them using the SpaceFM file manager, Google Chrome starts downloading the file instead of opening it like it does with the other mentioned file managers.

I am able to open these files through SpaceFM if I right click them and open with Firefox, but not Google Chrome.

An example of the desktop file would be as follows:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Link to The Hidden Fortress (1958) - IMDb
Type=Link
URL=http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0051808/?ref_=nv_sr_2
Icon=text-html
```

Is there a way to make these `.desktop` files open in Google Chrome normally when launched from the SpaceFM browser?

Comment: can anyone please help ?

Comment: ha! nice of you to come to the rescue @JacobVlijm. The links are always dragged from CHrome browser to a folder on my desktop, then moved to other folders.

Comment: observation * if you drag & drop a `.dektop` file  from any file manager into chrome it will download the file instead of opening the link, so it seems as though SpaceFM is treating the action as though it were Drag & Drop.

Comment: https://github.com/IgnorantGuru/spacefm/issues/638

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Convert link files into launchers

The solution below offers the option to right- click the link (`.desktop` file) and choose > "Execute", which will run `Google-Chrome` to open the link. By editing `SpaceFm`'s settings, you can run the link by double-click as well (see notes `[3]`).

[image]

Note that the solution automatically *edits* (only) *new* links on your desktop, to run the link specifically with `Google-Chrome`

#### What it is

A small background script checks once per two seconds for *new* `.desktop` files on your Desktop. If a relevant file is found, the file is edited from a *Link* file into an *Application* file. This is done by editing two lines inside the file:

- The line:

  ```
  Type=Link
  ```

  is changed into:

  ```
  Type=Application
  ```
- The line:

  ```
  URL=<link>
  ```

  is changed into:

  ```
  Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable <link>
  ```

In the test(s) I ran, this makes the link "openable" by right- click in `SpaceFm`: right-click > Open > Execute

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import time

# --- define the (absolute) path to your desktop below
dr = "/absolute/path/to/your/desktop"
# edit (if necessary) the command to launch Google-Chrome
application = "/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable"

def find_relevant():
    return [f for f in os.listdir(dr) if f.endswith(".desktop")]

relevant1 = []

while True:
    time.sleep(2)
    relevant2 = [f for f in os.listdir(dr) if f.endswith(".desktop")]
    new = [f for f in relevant2 if not f in relevant1]
    if new:
        for f in new:
            f = dr+"/"+f
            rewrite = False
            lines = [l.strip() for l in open(f).readlines()]
            for i, l in enumerate(lines):
                if l.startswith("Type=Link"):
                    rewrite = True
                    lines[i] = "Type=Application"
                elif l.startswith("URL="):
                    lines[i] = l.replace("URL=", "Exec="+application+" ")
            if rewrite == True:
                print("rewrite")
                open(f, "wt").write(("\n").join(lines))            
    relevant1 = relevant2
```

#### How to use

1. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `edit_links.py`
2. In the head- section of your script, edit the path to your Desktop (as mentioned, use absolute path here)
3. Check the command to run `Google-Chrome` (also set in the head- section) by checking the first `Exec=` line in the `google-chrome.desktop` file: run

   ```
   gedit /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
   ```

   to read the file.
4. Test-run the script by the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/edit_links.py
   ```

   Open `Google-Chrome`, drag links on to your Desktop, test after a few seconds if it works fine.
5. If all works fine, add it to Startup Applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add. Add the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/edit_links.py
   ```

#### Note

1. The dragged `.desktop` file (link) needs to be on your Desktop at least one-two seconds to be found and edited, so if you move the links, at least leave them for a few seconds on your Desktop. :)
2. ll the script does is check for new `.desktop` files on your Desktop, it only reads/edits the file(s) if there are new files. This means *nothing* to your system.
3. By editing `SpaceFm`'s settings, you can alsu run the "link" by double-click:

   [image]

#### Convert your existing link files recursively

Additionally, as discussed in chat, a script to run a single time to convert the links in a directory recursively:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys

# --- define the (absolute) path to your desktop below
dr = sys.argv[1]
# edit (if necessary) the command to launch Google-Chrome
application = "/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dr):
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith(".desktop"):
            f = root+"/"+f
            rewrite = False
            lines = [l.strip() for l in open(f).readlines()]
            for i, l in enumerate(lines):
                if l.startswith("Type=Link"):
                    rewrite = True
                    lines[i] = "Type=Application"
                elif l.startswith("URL="):
                    lines[i] = l.replace("URL=", "Exec="+application+" ")
            if rewrite == True:
                open(f, "wt").write(("\n").join(lines))
```

To use it, save it as `convert_links.py`, run it with the targeted directory as an argument:

```
python3 /path/to/convert_links.py <directory>
```

---

### 2. Convert links into cross-platform usable link files

As requested by OP, below a version of the (first) (background) script, converting the link files, created by dragging a link from the browser to the desktop, into ***cross-platform*** links. Usage is exactly as explained in the first section.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import time

# --- define the (absolute) path to your desktop below
dr = "/absolute/path/to/your/desktop"

out1 = ["<html>", "<body>", '<script type="text/javascript">']
out2 = ["</script>", "</body>", "</html>"]

def find_relevant():
    return [f for f in os.listdir(dr) if f.endswith(".desktop")]

relevant1 = []

while True:
    time.sleep(2)
    relevant2 = [f for f in os.listdir(dr) if f.endswith(".desktop")]
    new = [f for f in relevant2 if not f in relevant1]
    if new:
        for f in new:
            f = dr+"/"+f
            rewrite = False
            lines = [l.strip() for l in open(f).readlines()]
            for i, l in enumerate(lines):
                if l.startswith("Type=Link"):
                    rewrite = True
                elif l.startswith("URL="): 
                    url = 'window.location.href = "'+l.replace("URL=", "")+'"'
                    out1.append(url)
                elif l.startswith("Name="):
                    name = l.replace("Name=", "")
            if rewrite == True:
                open(f.replace(".desktop", ".html"), "wt").write(("\n").join(out1+out2))
                os.remove(f)
    relevant1 = relevant2
```

#### Version to convert your existing links in a recursive directory (single run)

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys

dr = sys.argv[1]

out1 = ["<html>", "<body>", '<script type="text/javascript">']
out2 = ["</script>", "</body>", "</html>"]

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dr):
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith(".desktop"):
            f = root+"/"+f
            rewrite = False
            lines = [l.strip() for l in open(f).readlines()]
            for i, l in enumerate(lines):
                if l.startswith("Type=Link"):
                    rewrite = True
                elif l.startswith("URL="): 
                    url = 'window.location.href = "'+l.replace("URL=", "")+'"'
                    out1.append(url)
                elif l.startswith("Name="):
                    name = l.replace("Name=", "")
            if rewrite == True:
                open(f.replace(".desktop", ".html"), "wt").write(("\n").join(out1+out2))
                os.remove(f)
```

To use it, save it as `convert_links.py`, run it with the targeted directory as an argument:

```
python3 /path/to/convert_links.py <directory>
```

#### Note

This version was based on [this nice answer](https://superuser.com/a/538093/323017) on Super User to create cross-platform links.

Comment: Excellent work, but something isn't quite working. The files have changed to - `Type=Application` with `http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0449467/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1` but still are being downloaded by CHrome instead of opened

Comment: Oh wait, yes, execute works fine, but not double click! Ok, got it. Looks like you're getting some more of my $$ tonight ha-ha.

Comment: while your script may have solved my SpaceFM problem on my Ubuntu machine, it creates another problem for the same files on my OSX machine. Simply put, these `.desktop` files will be shared on computers with different operating systems, and OSX does not know how to open this kind of modified `.desktop` file, so I am going to need an actual solution instead of a workaround.

Comment: It would be good to see a solution that would work so that users don't have to modify the files, as links are often shared over different platforms (like OSX and Windows), both of which would not be able to read the modified `.desktop` files described in this (brilliant) workaround. =)

Comment: agreed. I will mark your answer as the solution. I am in touch with developers, and they are looking into it. Thanks again.

Comment: Works like a charm on Ubuntu with SPaceFM and OSX chrome. YOu did it.